# how to route dynamically in store.js file in vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, vuex

I have a function in store.js (vuex), that check some conditions, if satisfies,
it should initiate route to another component.

`this.$router.push()` is not working in store.js .

Neither `vm.$router.push()` is working ,here  `vm = new Vue()` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** *You don't need to use vue instance for referring router, just import router and then use its methods.*

suppose your `router.js` looks like this.

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router';

Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    /* ... */
  ],
});
```

then you can import it in your `store.js`

```
import router from './router';
```

so that you can use it in your `store.js` like this.

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import router from './router';

Vue.use(Vuex);

const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        username: '',
    },
    mutations: {
      updateUsername(state, payload) {
          state.username = payload;
      }
    },
    actions: {
        updateUsername({ commit }, payload) {
            commit('updateUsername', payload);
            router.push('/');  // <--- router
        },
    },
});
```